# How to update PlayOnLinux?

Tags: playonlinux

I just installed PlayOnLinux, it says:

```
  An updated version of PlayOnLinux is available (3.8.11).
```

and nothing more.

Doing `apt-get update` doesn't offer any updated version of POL.

What is the safe / regular way to update playonlinux?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Did you check the repositorys?

> Type the following commands:
>
> ```
> wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O - | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_maverick.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install playonlinux
> ```

If you already did, running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` should install the latest version.

You can find the above code for your current version (for future reference) on the following link:
http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html

Comment: @ring0 Just added this ppa,and updated with it. It does give 3.8.11.

Comment: Thanks. There is a consistency problem on the design, imo, if the repo is not added, POL should not talk about an update (outside the repo from which it is installed). Anyway, this is a Linux problem...

Answer (score 4):

The best way to update Play on Linux is to go to [their main website](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) and download the package from there, and install it manually. Just download the .deb file and open it up. Use the software package manager for it. It should automatically install just like an .exe, that simple.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the link, but this is what I'm trying to avoid. Such an installation will not benefit from the *update* system. POL is installed via Ubuntu Software center and I would like to find a way to get updates via **apt-get update**.

Comment: The problem is the Ubuntu repositories do not update immediately after a third-party vendor (read: playonlinux) makes an update. There really is no way around this unless playonlinux makes a ppa.

Answer (score 0):

There's a successor to PlayOnLinux recommended in the README of the original source code repository: https://www.phoenicis.org/. It's under development, but might be worth a try. It can be installed through flathub.