# Unable to find version: 4.2 while installing photoshop cs6 on playonlinux

Tags: software-installation, wine, playonlinux, photoshop

Steps:

1. Downloaded photoshop cs6 and extracted it.
2. Went to **playonlinux > Graphics > Photoshop CS6**
3. On browse, linked the `set-up.exe` and clicked on <kbd>next</kbd> to install photoshop

But I got the following error:

> Error in POL_Wine_InstallVersion
>   Unable to find version: 4.2

None of the tutorials I find online have mentioned this issue related to 4.2. 
Also, they seem to use old wine and it seems to work just fine.

Please help.

My system info is:

- Laptop Model: Dell Inspiron i7 7559
- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- Memory: 7.7 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
- Graphics: GeForce GTX 960M/PCIe/SSE2
- GNOME: 3.28.2
- OS type: 64-bit

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error so I added the repository in order to download the latest version of PlayOnLinux.

[How to update PlayOnLinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28801/how-to-update-playonlinux)

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_maverick.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

It then updated Wine and downloaded and installed the necessary dependencies for me.

However it didn't work first time, I then had to go to the following link to get the updated installer.
https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2316-Adobe_Photoshop_CS6.html

I now have it running on PopOs 18.10.  Shame the pressure sensitivity on my tablet doesn't work but hey, you can't have it all.